# Where can I find information about when Electronic Diversity Visa Lottery for 2022 will start?

Tags: usa, greencard

Where can I find information about when Electronic Diversity Visa Lottery for 2022 will start?
When I open official site https://dvprogram.state.gov/ I can't find any information or notice when it will become open for applications.

I have seen many non-official site which accept applications for 2022 Electronic Diversity Visa Lottery but they require payment for registration and I feel confused, since I guess it should be free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diversity visa always opens at the beginning of October.  As far as I am aware, this is because the US federal government's accounting year runs from October 1st through September 30th.

I have found some unofficial sources saying that the 2022 program will go ahead as usual in October 2020, but I haven't found any official source.  Given the current political climate, particularly the COVID restrictions on immigrant visas, it would not be terribly surprising if it were cancelled.  If I were you I would keep checking the page you linked to as well as the [DV section of the State Department's public information site](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/diversity-visa-program-entry/diversity-visa-submit-entry1.html).